# How to let an event in WinForms C# know the statements/declarations that are in the other events?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ bool b=false;   
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b=true;
    }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(b)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("hello");
          }
    }
}
```

What i mean is the `if` statement in `Form1`doesn't know that the boolean `b` is true when i click on the `button1`.

`b` stays false in `Form1` because i declared it as that in the beginning before the events.

So how can i make `Form1` here know that `b` is true when i click on `button1`?

Like how to connect/relate events?

In general how can i make the statements in an event know what happens in other events like here?

Comment: You need to look into the order of events. The variable `b` will never be true in the Load event handler.

Comment: The FormLoad event will called once before it is shown the first time. So it will never be called after you hit a button on the form. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Load` event of a form is the first event to be raised in the form. And it is raised only once in each forms life time.

When a form is loaded, the stuff you declare between events and methods (in the body of your form) are created, then the constructor of the form is invoked (the one with `InitializeComponent();` in it), and finally, the loaded event (if there is one) is raised.

Now, the default value of a `Boolean` variable is `false` (you've even set it to false manualy), so the `button1_Click` event which sets your boolean's value to true, will never be raised before the form's loaded event

Ergo what you want can't be achieved, unless, you store the boolean value to the database after each time the button is clicked, and read it from the database in the form upon loading.

I'd appreciate it if you accepted the answer, in case it helped clear things up.

Comment: "you store the boolean value to the database after each time the button is clicked, and read it from the database in the form upon loading", how can i do that please?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with storing data in database, I can't teach you in a two paragraph text. search "saving and retrieving data to database in C#", there are many helpful videos on youtube. but if you get stuck or need clarification, comment again here, or ask a new question and tag me in the question